# Error in npm run build in apache superset plugin

Tags: apache-superset

**`your text`Following the steps:
https://preset.io/blog/building-custom-viz-plugins-in-superset-v2/

While running npm run build in the plugin, it is throwing error:

superset-plugin-chart-hello-world@0.1.0 build-esm
BABEL_OUTPUT=esm babel src --extensions ".ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx" --copy-files --out-dir esm

```
'BABEL_OUTPUT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

and the esm folder is not created.

On running

```
    BABEL_OUTPUT=esm babel src --extensions ".ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx" --copy-files --out-dir esm
```

It is throwing error:
[image]
Am I missing something?

followed the exact steps

Tried
npm ci
npm run build

But no luck.
esm folder is not created and failing build**

Comment: Are you using Windows?
Anyways, here is a link which might help you out https://www.tetranyde.com/blog/superset-viz-plugin-custom